# Connecting cooker to UK 3 pin socket

Tags: electrical, cabling, cord-and-plug

I have just bought an electric cooker, and I haven't got anything to connect it to the three pin socket I have at home (I am in the UK). What should I buy and where should I connect the three (live, neutral, earth) wires (see photos )? The earth cable should go under the right-hand screw, but what about the others?

[Photo1](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/eO1ed_9M9qRWYGW5v1nG-NejEywe0Z445h5XVdHZayZj1hFht2pAEWz1D0DcapE2k1uJpDsY1Y8X0Nhjx1qdgCvkHd9uYnTcfTPwMNqUm-WAiULeB9jVT1cFsIg9M9CFBDjo7rB3O4u6T0fD_FCn_4GfBItcTzlg-HiiuoCaoTLg9KOvQt4dsEyjRWlnyItZbNVKgKq0zF-fIizUfauT84SJEjncPRJyn7kbLXJnmfdQGq9N0ODtkh_J0_Nj4Eyel-uJ-0HKPJ3pKr8AID8mVYxVRkZ1zl_SmXSbw6-AwliWODMzRq8qx8rtl6LSo-avmj1tcHReRFlQidnYwEGztSp_nBEW1KtsM0k3IfoqMwF45vJ7u5AVh6jPBupNQf_Y8mxsdEFVgwO0P42AkAiI7jje0nhsZqrzcXBt3R5OqT2NKmghK399mkjUWWxrIUe-I8bredcDtTr8R-cmDIONA8U3z4miDn3yVGjCOJAcQzCYFO517v-2ppFHAKWIi0y78IAej7-hbTKPXDZAAscI5TXvods4T8apcwmmPYTrt97nfnOul-FFRrPJE8f0ldSifVsopK_YZftJnrr5BNKO8ZK3a1idjJ-pN59wT6FehldhoG3VnvY-q4RN6Bqi9Y3U16Kt6oHTmUqg7GyfEyORCQQJNAL8eFWqG80yVCtLA1A=w2736-h1538-no)

[Photo2](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/z287mYkmOimFbR9gJND32folcrUAnX5TVPamOEACNXf_0aE-rVgkI75y1-EWYTajJe-9Dxfw6uJzDwHE9u3cg2rhMgDAEipPtbt2ux8yo9hWoBdxnLRauqslxJerdsRHLy1-cj5_7Iye1OU0ESJYI0zEa5p7SkJmeDC3m440OaQdqDp6kXTdkc-f9KsVEjZhK8uZ3BOgOEIw2xZ_kNx7JHeMqe1Nhl_ndf5KckRcwZMIsDYR_RbYaSXR_pdstO9NLxv_O9eVM_xECgm-da8zfxuKs31TuuvHYEaloqnV911mipFWMS3o2t9m7OzTIHs8yc37Mlf5qH7D2Yfe3G59mao2wHEuOP32aHrSI54-gjYE5Ca2nw3bBOeylDSG4ELdx5vrr4frjz-olGSEvbbh3iDhMELc4r7veMNe97aYkXtJTFBb1W5uz-8VticPcHlCk4QHDJsIjpSD0V_RNQQ-hbkI3Ci7gkU7_-eAFrxBM3N7GlbAjGoAwHvcIYVsNPsF2a2sIrVPzdMOPJdPdzi4rhjwhAvGGcLflDKa2qSnY48LnaEmYbMKhJflD_xHioB871Png1U7M8chAURCsW9uEKzFE2Tb5N9nloBBSAmRX2S7R9g8r-uke3RfngNpZakJkRN7PKq5zYKB4gxF-8HFszjUeoa0y1jJmMSn3vX7Pjg=w866-h1538-nohttps://lh3.googleusercontent.com/z287mYkmOimFbR9gJND32folcrUAnX5TVPamOEACNXf_0aE-rVgkI75y1-EWYTajJe-9Dxfw6uJzDwHE9u3cg2rhMgDAEipPtbt2ux8yo9hWoBdxnLRauqslxJerdsRHLy1-cj5_7Iye1OU0ESJYI0zEa5p7SkJmeDC3m440OaQdqDp6kXTdkc-f9KsVEjZhK8uZ3BOgOEIw2xZ_kNx7JHeMqe1Nhl_ndf5KckRcwZMIsDYR_RbYaSXR_pdstO9NLxv_O9eVM_xECgm-da8zfxuKs31TuuvHYEaloqnV911mipFWMS3o2t9m7OzTIHs8yc37Mlf5qH7D2Yfe3G59mao2wHEuOP32aHrSI54-gjYE5Ca2nw3bBOeylDSG4ELdx5vrr4frjz-olGSEvbbh3iDhMELc4r7veMNe97aYkXtJTFBb1W5uz-8VticPcHlCk4QHDJsIjpSD0V_RNQQ-hbkI3Ci7gkU7_-eAFrxBM3N7GlbAjGoAwHvcIYVsNPsF2a2sIrVPzdMOPJdPdzi4rhjwhAvGGcLflDKa2qSnY48LnaEmYbMKhJflD_xHioB871Png1U7M8chAURCsW9uEKzFE2Tb5N9nloBBSAmRX2S7R9g8r-uke3RfngNpZakJkRN7PKq5zYKB4gxF-8HFszjUeoa0y1jJmMSn3vX7Pjg=w866-h1538-no)

Comment: What make and model is the cooker?

Comment: Zanussi ZCV662MWC

Answer (score 2):

The electric cooker should have an installation manual. Most electric cookers in the UK are not plugged into a normal 13A wall outlet/socket. They are hardwired to a dual-pole cooker switch on a dedicated cooker circuit (e.g. a dedicated 32A circuit).

A typical cooker instructions will say something similar to this example.

> The cooker must be connected by a competent
>   person  such  as  one  who  is  a,  NICEIC  registered
>   contractor to a suitable double-pole control unit with
>   a  minimum  rating  of  32A  and  a  minimum  contact
>   clearance  of  3mm  (applicable  to  newer  properties,
>   older properties where a 30A double pole control unit
>   and a minimum contact clearance of 3mm is
>   acceptable).
>   The double pole control unit should be fitted
>   adjacent to the cooker, in accordance with IEE
>   regulations.  The  control  unit  must  be  within  2  metres
>   of  but  not  directly  above  the  appliance  and  should
>   be  easily  accessible  in  the  event  of  an  emergency.
>   The  power  supply  cable  should  conform  to  B.S.6004
>   with  a  conductor  size  of  6mm2,  minimum.
>   Access  to  the  mains  terminals  is  gained  by
>   removing  the  rear  access  cover.  The  mains  cable
>   must  pass  through  the  cable  clamp  adjacent  to  the
>   terminal  block.  Sufficient  cable  should  be  used  to
>   allow  the  cooker  to  be  pulled  out  for  servicing.
>   Ensure that the mains cable is routed away
>   from any brackets affixed to the rear panel and
>   is not trapped to the rear wall when pushing the
>   cooker  into  position  between  cabinets

Examples of the required diversity calculations can be found online. For example: https://www.tlc-direct.co.uk/Book/6.5.2.htm

In your photo of your cooker's connectors, the multiple live and neutral connections appear to be each be connected by a copper bus bar. This presumably means that you can attach the supply to any of the screw terminals (brown to an "L", blue to an "N"). Don't use 13A flex or a 13A plug, it'll eventually blow the fuse or catch fire.